# algorithm2e not showing caption with iucr document class

Tags: captions, algorithms, algorithm2e

I am preparing a manuscript to be submitted to a IUCr journal. By using the provided template (http://journals.iucr.org/s/services/latexstyle.html) where the `documentclass` is set to `iucr`, I found my algorithm boxes created using `algorithm2e` were not showing captions. The captions of figures were displayed normally. After switching to `\documentclass{article}`, the algorithm box captions came back to normal.

An MWE is listed below:

```
\documentclass[preprint]{iucr} 
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\RestyleAlgo{boxruled}

\begin{document} 
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwIn{$g$: the scan grid configuration}
\KwIn{$\Theta$: the list of projection angles}
\For{$z$ in $g_z$}{
  \For{$y$ in $g_y$}{
    \For{$x$ in $g_x$}{
      \For{$\theta$ in $\Theta$}{
          Acquire projection image
      }
    }
  }
}
End Acquisition
\label{box:acq_local}
\caption{Algorithm for image acquisition used for local tomogram stitching.}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The printed algorithm box looks like this - although `\caption` is provided, its missing in the pdf.
[image]

The `cls` file of the IUCr template can be found via the link above.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Please post the class file here as well, I don't want to follow external links in order to pursue this issue

Comment: The codes are too long to be placed in the post, is there another way to present it with the issue?

Comment: Label have to placed after caption.

Comment: I attempted to change the position of label, but it didn't help with this case.

Comment: @koleygr: Yes, but that's unrelated to the main issue here.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I thought to write "off-topic" in the message for this reason... but didn't "herd" correct  to me... (Now that I thought it, in such cases I will write "Not the main issue"...)

Comment: @koleygr: `Off-topic` is perfectly ok and shorter than `Not the main issue`

Answer (score 1):

The `iucr` class redefines `\caption` based on whether the float is a figure or a table (or a class-specific `example` environment). Unfortunately there is no default case for other types of float, such as algorithms, which means that for these floats the definition of `\caption` is blank.

You can provide a custom command for the caption (borrowed from `article`) and use that for all floats other than figures and tables. It appears that this solution preserves numbering and correct references (see example below).

Note that the journal may have additional requirements on the placement, font style, abbreviation etc. of custom captions. Also: it may be a good idea to mention to the journal editor that this issue should be addressed in their document class.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[preprint]{iucr} 
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\RestyleAlgo{boxruled}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycaption}{%
\ifx \@captype \@undefined \@latex@error {\noexpand \caption outside float}\@ehd \expandafter \@gobble \else \refstepcounter \@captype \expandafter \@firstofone \fi {\@dblarg {\@caption \@captype }}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Consider Figures \ref{fig:first} and \ref{fig:second} and Algorithms \ref{box:acq_local} and \ref{box:acq_short}.

\begin{figure}
\fbox{A figure}
\caption{Figure caption}
\label{fig:first}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}
\SetAlgoLined
\KwIn{$g$: the scan grid configuration}
\KwIn{$\Theta$: the list of projection angles}
\For{$z$ in $g_z$}{
  \For{$y$ in $g_y$}{
    \For{$x$ in $g_x$}{
      \For{$\theta$ in $\Theta$}{
          Acquire projection image
      }
    }
  }
}
End Acquisition
\mycaption{Algorithm for image acquisition used for local tomogram stitching.}
\label{box:acq_local}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{figure}
\fbox{Another figure}
\caption{Other figure caption}
\label{fig:second}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}
\SetAlgoLined
\KwIn{$g$: the scan grid configuration}
\KwIn{$\Theta$: the list of projection angles}
Do Magic\;
End Acquisition
\mycaption{Short algorithm for image acquisition.}
\label{box:acq_short}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It worked out smoothly, thank you so much! I will definitely mention the issue to the editors.